# Sagemaker batch transform job failure for 'batchStrategy: MultiRecord' along with data processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, batch-processing, amazon-sagemaker

We are using SageMaker Batch Transform job and to fit as many records in a mini-batch as can fit within the `MaxPayloadInMB` limit, we are setting `BatchStrategy` to `MultiRecord` and `SplitType` to `Line`.

Input to the SageMaker batch transform job is:

```
{"requestBody": {"data": {"Age": 90, "Experience": 26, "Income": 30, "Family": 3, "CCAvg": 1}}, "mName": "loanprediction", "mVersion": "1", "testFlag": "false", "environment": "DEV", "transactionId": "5-687sdf87-0bc7e3cb3454dbf261ed1353", "timestamp": "2022-01-15T01:45:32.955Z"}
{"requestBody": {"data": {"Age": 55, "Experience": 26, "Income": 450, "Family": 3, "CCAvg": 1}}, "mName": "loanprediction", "mVersion": "1", "testFlag": "false", "environment": "DEV", "transactionId": "5-69e22778-594916685f4ceca66c08bfbc", "timestamp": "2022-01-15T01:46:32.386Z"}
```

This is the SageMaker batch transform job config:

```
apiVersion: sagemaker.aws.amazon.com/v1
kind: BatchTransformJob
metadata:
        generateName: '...-batchtransform'
spec:
        batchStrategy: MultiRecord
        dataProcessing:
                JoinSource: Input
                OutputFilter: $
                inputFilter: $.requestBody
        modelClientConfig:
                invocationsMaxRetries: 0
                invocationsTimeoutInSeconds: 3
        mName: '..'
        region: us-west-2
        transformInput:
                contentType: application/json
                dataSource:
                        s3DataSource:
                                s3DataType: S3Prefix
                                s3Uri: s3://....../part-
                splitType: Line
        transformOutput:
                accept: application/json
                assembleWith: Line
                kmsKeyId: '....'
                s3OutputPath: s3://..../batch_output
        transformResources:
                instanceCount: ..
                instanceType: '..'
```

The SageMaker batch transform job fails with:

Error in batch transform data-log -

> 2022-01-27T00:55:39.781:[sagemaker logs]:
> ephemeral-dev-435945521637/loanprediction-usw2-dev/my-loanprediction/1/my-pipeline-9v28r/part-00001-99fb4b99-e8e7-4945-ac44-b6c5a95a2ffe-c000.txt:
>
> 2022-01-27T00:55:39.781:[sagemaker logs]:
> ephemeral-dev-435945521637/loanprediction-usw2-dev/my-loanprediction/1/my-pipeline-9v28r/part-00001-99fb4b99-e8e7-4945-ac44-b6c5a95a2ffe-c000.txt:
>
> 400 Bad Request 2022-01-27T00:55:39.781:[sagemaker
> logs]:
> ephemeral-dev-435945521637/loanprediction-usw2-dev/my-loanprediction/1/my-pipeline-9v28r/part-00001-99fb4b99-e8e7-4945-ac44-b6c5a95a2ffe-c000.txt:
>
> Failed to decode JSON object: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char
> 163)

**Observation:**
This issue occurs when we provide `batchStrategy: MultiRecord` in the manifest along with these data processing configs:

```
dataProcessing:
        JoinSource: Input
        OutputFilter: $
        inputFilter: $.requestBody
```

**NOTE:** If we put `batchStrategy: SingleRecord` along with the aforementioned data processing configs, it just works fine (job succeeds)!

**Question:** How can we achieve successful run with `batchStrategy: MultiRecord` along with the aforementioned data processing config?

A successful output with `batchStrategy: SingleRecord` looks like this:

> {"SageMakerOutput":{"prediction":0},"environment":"DEV","transactionId":"5-687sdf87-0bc7e3cb3454dbf261ed1353","mName":"loanprediction","mVersion":"1","requestBody":{"data":{"Age":90,"CCAvg":1,"Experience":26,"Family":3,"Income":30}},"testFlag":"false","timestamp":"2022-01-15T01:45:32.955Z"}
> {"SageMakerOutput":{"prediction":0},"environment":"DEV","transactionId":"5-69e22778-594916685f4ceca66c08bfbc","mName":"loanprediction","mVersion":"1","requestBody":{"data":{"Age":55,"CCAvg":1,"Experience":26,"Family":3,"Income":450}},"testFlag":"false","timestamp":"2022-01-15T01:46:32.386Z"}
> Region name – optional: Relevant resource ARN – optional:
> arn:aws:sagemaker:us-west-2:435945521637:transform-job/my-pipeline-9v28r-bat-e548fbfb125946528957e0f123456789

Comment: Does the answer works for u? I have the same problem like u and I changed to jsonlines but still failed

Comment: @MPA Our container can only handle single json at a time, so we could not use `MultiRecord` hence kept it `SingleRecord` only.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70980502/948268

Comment: So, I understand that i need to implement it by mysellf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your input data is in JSON line format and you choose a SingleRecord BatchStrategy, your container will receive a single JSON payload body like below

```
{ <some JSON data> }
```

However, if you use MultiRecord, Batch transform will split your JSON line input (which might contain 100 lines for example) into multiple records (say 10 records) all sent at once to your container as shown below:

```
{ <some JSON data> }
{ <some JSON data> }
{ <some JSON data> }
{ <some JSON data> }
.
.
.
{ <some JSON data> }
```

Therefore your container should be able to handle such input for it to work. However, from the error message, I can see it is complaining about invalid JSON format as it reads the second row of the request.

I also noticed that you have supplied `ContentType` and `AcceptType` as `application/json` but instead should be `application/jsonlines`

Could you please test your container to see if it can handle multiple JSON line records per single invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use dataProcessing to join input with prediction when using MultiRecord. You will need to merge manually the input with prediction separately after batch processing job. MultiRecord strategy process records in batches with maximum size specified in MaxPayloadInMB.

For the input in:

```
input1 

input2

input3

input4

input5

input6
```

The output would be in below format:

```
output1,output2,output3

output3,output4,output6
```

You will need to process the output file to merge with input data to get desired outcome. I expect an json array for predictions as  your output format is json. You can explode the array and merge it with the input. You need to maintain the order of prediction when you explode it. You can find more details on:

https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_batch_transform/introduction_to_batch_transform/batch_transform_pca_dbscan_movie_clusters.html#Batch-prediction-on-new-data

Comment: Thanks @ajay, Does AWS docs say this anywhere `You can not use dataProcessing to join input with prediction when using MultiRecord`. Moreover, as per @Rohan's answer, if my model container can accept and process jsonlines then also I cannot use dataProcessing to join input?

Comment: I couldn't find any document for the same but we faced similar issue with our batch transform job. We reached out to AWS customer service and they suggested the solutions as described in the Answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.